# Opening the file browser from terminal

Tags: command-line

What's the command to open the file browser? I want it so that I can assign a keyboard shortcut to open a specific folder.

Comment: I add an & after command, whatever it is, so the terminal stays available for new commands. 
Appending space & after a command runs it in its own environment, dissociating it from the terminal.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

`nautilus --browser` will ensure that Nautilus is launched in browser mode even if you're normally using it in spatial mode.

You can append the path you want to open to the end:

```
nautilus --browser ~/some/directory
```

Comment: But the problem I have with `nautilus` is that it has root permissions. How can I avoid that? I don't want to accidentally delete any files.

Comment: It shouldn't have root permissions unless you launch it with `gksudo`.

Comment: simply you can type nautilus in command text. I have done the same shorcut using Win+E for opening nautilus

Comment: this seems to work OK, but throws [a ton of errors](http://askubuntu.com/q/803259/453746) for me [and others](http://askubuntu.com/q/689478/453746).

Comment: Most of this solutions need a running instance of nautilus, which on most environments is started to show the desktop icons. If not you will get a message like
`Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying`
I had to enable my desktop icons using
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true`

Comment: what if the location is accessed through ssh???

Answer (score 62):

The [`gnome-open`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/gnome-open.1.html) command will open a directory with the appropriate application, which in this case is Nautilus:

```bsh
gnome-open PATH
```

This will open the directory `/tmp` using the Nautilus file browser.

```bsh
gnome-open /tmp
```

Or:

```bsh
cd /tmp
gnome-open .
```

I like the `gnome-open` command because you can use this exact same command to open a file with the appropriate application. No need to remember any funny flags. It just works.

- `gnome-open file.pdf` will open the PDF in a PDF browser.
- `gnome-open file.zip` will open a zip file using the Zip archive viewer.

It's also similar in name and function to the Mac OS X `open` command, for those of us who use Macs.

Comment: To update this answer: gnome-open is now called gvfs-open. If you want a desktop-agnostic command, you can also use xdg-open.

Comment: This leaves the terminal hanging awaiting more input, so you have to kill with Ctrl-C

Comment: @JeffPuckettII In my experience, `gnome-open file.ext` will open a file, hand it off to another program and then exit. It does not hang awaiting for more input, at least not on my Ubuntu 14.04 box at home.

Comment: To update @JasonChampion's update: `gvfs-open` is now deprecated, replaced by a small shell script that calls `gio open`. `xdg-open` is also a wrapper script, and on most Ubuntu systems it's likely to call `gio open`. `gnome-open` still exists as a binary distinct from `gio`

Answer (score 61):

As of 2018, one can use the [GIO commandline tool](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio.html) on Gnome:

```
gio open some/directory
```

*Edit*: Another option is [xdg-open](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html). Also take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1046404/67341) for further details.

Comment: `gio open .`
OR
`sudo nautilus` 

These works.
Thanks

Answer (score 38):

For me the safest way that is compatible with almost all environments is [xdg-open](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xdg-open.1.html)

```
xdg-open $HOME/test
```

This would open a directory named test (for example) under your home directory.

Comment: this is the better answer, compared the accepted answer. The reason is: nautlius opens a folder but it hangs the command line until you closed the opened File Explorer, but this one opens the file explorer and you can still use command line.

Comment: For me, this option also hangs the command line... (Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: A general rule for **all** GUI application is: if you don't want them to hang the command line, run them in background, ie. add `&` at the end of the command. Like: `nautilus --browser &`

Answer (score 14):

For reference, I'm running Ubuntu Bionic 18.04.

The easiest and safest way I open the file explorer from command line is with the `xdg-open` command, which itself often aliased as the `browse` command if that's more your style. `xdg-open` ships natively with Ubuntu.

`xdg-open` can also open any file or web URL, and will open it according to your computer's default application for files of that filetype.

Examples:

`browse .`
Opens the file explorer in my current directory.

`xdg-open ~` Does the same, but my home directory.

`xdg-open https://www.google.ca` Launches google's homepage with your default browser (xdg-open will open it as a new tab if a browser session is already open).

Man pages for `xdg-open` can be found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xdg-open.1.html)

Note that the xdg-open command is not meant to be used with root priveleges.

Answer (score 13):

I put the following line in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias opn="nautilus -s ."
```

Now you can open with

```
$ opn /path/to/folder
```

Comment: There is a command named `open` already in package `kbd`, it's linked to `openvt`.

Comment: Working in Ubuntu 18.04 too, unlike some of the other answers here.

Answer (score 5):

On ubuntu 20.04 run: `browse ./directory_path`

Answer (score 4):

You can use

- `nautilus PATH` for the Gnome
- `nemo PATH` for the Cinnamon
- `caja PATH` for the MATE
- `thunar PATH` for the Xfce

Answer (score 1):

Since I am used to `explorer .` I add an alias to my linux systems.

```
echo 'alias explorer="gio open"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

On a **new** terminal I can:

```
explorer .
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nautilus`

For root file browsing, it's `gksudo nautilus`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using nautilus for current directory -> `nautilus ./`
2. Using gnome-open for current directory -> `gnome-open ./`
   For gnome-open you might be required to install `sudo apt install libgnome2-bin`

Comment: Someone voted it down, I can't understand why. 
We have to type nautilus. at a folder, we want file explorer. 
nautilus is installed by default with ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

The de facto way in current dabian / *buntu way is now with `xdg-open` see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144048/152563) which is interesting.  If you're using bash shell, you may find
this script to be helpful especially if you're coming from MacOS using terminal `open` command.

Here's the [bash version](https://gist.github.com/ozanmuyes/ea92b8eaba34d9c57894f05751270118)

Here's the [ported to zsh version](https://gist.github.com/lacostenycoder/3ad934aab2017bcb788deb66778ef26d)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply open using a directory in File explorer using

```
gio open ./ path/to/folder
```

Comment: This won't open a file browser.