# How to be granted root rights while browsing files/directories with Nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, sudo

I'd like to know if there a way to be granted root rights while using Nautilus 2.30 ?

For example I'd like to move some old folders of long unused users from the home directory - remains of previous distros (Debian).

Of course I can open a terminal, but I want to know if it is possible to do that with a mouse in Nautilus.

Comment: `gksu` and `gksudo` work in Xorg but not in Wayland (which is default in Ubuntu 17.10). But there are ways to make it work. See this link, [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For Ubuntu <= 10.10 , 10.04**

## [nautilus-gksu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nautilus-gksu) [image: Install nautilus-gksu]

Is an extension that grants root privileges using gksu nautilus.

It enables an option when you right-click on a file (also directories and other...) in nautilus: "Open as administrator".
After installing it restart Nautilus (`killall nautilus`) and it will have the new feature.

[image]

**Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10,**

install `nautilus-gksu` and copy and paste the `libnautilus-gksu.so` file from `/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0/` to `/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/`

**Ubuntu 12.04 & 12.10:**

The `nautilus-gksu` package has been dropped in Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 since `gksu` 2.0.2-6ubuntu1 release, so you can not install it easily. Here I’m going to use a nautilus script to add **Open As Administrator** functionality.

First download the `libnautilus-gksu.so` file:

[Click to Download libnautilus-gksu.so](http://www.handytutorial.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/libnautilus-gksu.so)

Then, run gksudo nautilus in terminal <kbd>Ctrl<kbd>+Alt</kbd>+T</kbd> to open the file browser with root privilege, copy and paste this file to `/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/`. Or do it with this command:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/libnautilus-gksu.so /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/
```

Log out and back in, or run this command to take effect:

```
nautilus -q
```

[image]

[Source](http://handytutorial.com/open-as-administrator-in-ubuntu-12-04-12-10/)

Comment: I install it right now ;-)

Comment: Guarantees root access without asking for password?

Comment: No it does ask the root password. Exactly what I wanted. :-). Thx.

Comment: This should really be included by default.

Comment: This no longer exists

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is mouse, I'd try opening a terminal and then:

```
$gksudo nautilus
```

I don't see the need to install anything

**edit:** this was covered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8580/opening-the-file-browser-from-terminal/8582#8582)

Comment: I think the difference is **really** clear. That's the same reason for installing sudo not using `su`. Having su rights only for a small and delimited time is less dangerous than having them during a whole session.

Answer (score 2):

### Ubuntu 12.04 and later

Nautilus Admin (*nautilus-admin*) is a simple Python extension for the Nautilus file manager that adds some administrative actions to the right-click menu:

- Open as Administrator: opens a folder in a new Nautilus window     running with administrator (root) privileges.
- Edit as Administrator: opens a file in a Gedit window running     with administrator (root) privileges.

To install Nautilus Admin in all  currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-admin
```

---

<sup>`gksu` is discontinued in the official 18.04 and later repositories.</sup>

Alternatively open the directory in nautilus as root from the terminal with a command of the form:

```
sudo -H nautilus /path/to/directory
```

#### Ubuntu 16.04 and earlier

[gksudo](/questions/tagged/gksudo) is a frontend to sudo. Its primary purpose is to run graphical programs as root.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu # install gksu if it is not already installed
gksudo nautilus
```

Enter your password in the window that pops up.

[image]

Comment: +1 to '**`cd`** in the terminal'. Yes, it is recommended to use text mode commands in a terminal (a terminal window in a graphical desktop environment), when you perform tasks that need elevated permissions.