# Error when using "sudo Nautilus", how do I solve it?

Tags: nautilus, sudo

Here is the terminal log.

http://pastebin.com/xTEK13B7

How do I fix it? What does it do? Is it safe or okay?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to be granted root rights while browsing files/directories with Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27767/how-to-be-granted-root-rights-while-browsing-files-directories-with-nautilus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nautilus is a graphical application so you ought to use `gksudo` instead :

```
gksudo nautilus
```

When you want to do graphical things with high prilivegies, `gksudo` and `gksu` are much more convinient than `sudo` and `su`.

Answer (score 0):

It is an uncritical message; nautilus should run normally; for reference see [this report at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/499288).

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 `gksudo` is gone.

Instead, try:

```
sudo -H nautilus
```