# Got these warnings when I run "sudo nautilus"

Tags: server, 20.04, xubuntu, system, codecs

```
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:70214): WARNING **: 09:38:12.193: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:70214): WARNING **: 09:38:12.194: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory
Nautilus-Share-Message: 09:38:12.300: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Nautilus isn't designed to be run as root. When using Nautilus in way that it's not designed for, those messages look like expected behavior: Root doesn't have a display assigned to it, and root has no bookmarks.

Comment: Better perhaps to install `nautilus-admin`. This will give the option to open folders and edit files as **admin**. When I want to open folders on a Live or Persistent USB as root, I use `sudo -H nautilus`.

Comment: Warnings are NOT errors. And please never use sudo for graphical applications.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to be granted root rights while browsing files/directories with Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27767/how-to-be-granted-root-rights-while-browsing-files-directories-with-nautilus)

Comment: @karel: Which answer on that page are you recommending? `gksu` has not worked in ages and I mention `nautilus-admin` above.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron https://askubuntu.com/a/827247, the one with `sudo apt install nautilus-admin`

Comment: Why make the OP look through a whole page of misinformation and try to figure out which answer works?

Comment: Is this a server installation? Have you installed a GUI desktop? Any difference if you `sudo -H nautilus`?