# How do you give write permission to GUI user in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 20.04, permissions, gui

I'm using Ubuntu in my personal computer.

It's annoying that I can't create folders, rename, delete etc. in GUI.

I don't want to write commands to create a simple folder or delete one.

Can someone please help me to do this. Thanks in advance

P.S. - please don't ask why do I wanna do that, or don't say, not to do that. I don't have any sensitive data on this computer. So I don't care if GUI user have root permissions.

And I want to use Ubuntu like this in day to day life. like in Windows PC. like a normal person.

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] your question accodingly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need an equivalent of gksu in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1042344/) and [How to be granted root rights while browsing files/directories with Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27767/how-to-be-granted-root-rights-while-browsing-files-directories-with-nautilus)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using gnome. You will obtain the permission to create, delete the folder in GUI by using the command

```
sudo nautilus
```

Comment: I am looking for a long term way to use this. not just for a single time. I want to edit, delete file like in Windows. like a normal person.