# How to install ‘Nautilus’ on VirtualBox and use it with ssh?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, nautilus, ssh

I installed Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager on Windows 7 and I was able to run some PHP programs on it. I use Git-Bash with Vagrant to access shell (Ubuntu).

I would like to try a simple Java web application on the above machine.

I installed 'Nautilus' file manager and I tried to open it in the terminal by running the command: `nautilus --browser` ([Opening the file browser from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/8583)), but I get an error message as follows:

```
(nautilus:8243): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Notes:

- 'X11Forwarding' is already ‘yes’ by default (`$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`).
- I installed all updates by running the commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```

  [Install VirtualBox Guest Additions In Ubuntu Guest Machines](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/01/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu-guest-machines/)

My question is how to install and access files and folders on the host machine using 'Nautilus’?

Comment: thanks for your response but I think that X server in your link, doesn't serve the VirtualBox machine.

Comment: Cygwin's X is for Windows. What do you mean, it doesn't server your VirtualBox machine?

Comment: it's not the same configuration, because I run ubuntu on a VirtualBox.

Comment: cygwin X is to be installed on windows, not Ubuntu.

Comment: [SOLVED] (1) **Windows:** Install Xming (2) **PuTTY:** Enable X11 Forwaring (3) **Server:** /etc/ssh/sshd_config (a) `X11Forwarding yes` (b) `X11DisplayOffset 10` (4) **Server:** Install xauth

Answer (score 1):

If you use "Bridge adapter" in the virtualbox network settings, try

```
ssh youruser@virtualboxhostname.local -X
nautilus
```

Comment: I run: `ssh vagrant@virtualbox.local -X` and I got: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname virtualbox.local: Name or service not known`

Comment: I meant replace virtualboxhostname with the hostname of your virtualbox. You can also use the IP without .local